# AJAX JSON not retrieving value

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc-3

From my controller I am passing a list called ccdata through JSON. 
It only has 1 record which is a list.

```
    return Json(rpata, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

In my view, I tried to pull the value of FirstName and LastName but got an error - 'FirstName.0' is null or not an object:

```
    $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
      url: '@Url.Action("GetRpInfo", "PgController")',
                 data: { ID: ID },
                 dataType: "json",
                 success: function (rpdata) {

                    var rpinfo = rpdata.FirstName[0] + " " + repdata.LastName[0];

              }
   });
```

Comment: Can you post the rest of your C# method?

Comment: it would help troubleshoot if you posted the actual JSON that your application was sending (or the browser was receiving)

Comment: Also, you can debug javascript and see the object strucure of `rpdata`. You can use Firebug in Firefox, or Chrome built in Javascript Console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isn't this what you need?

```
var rpinfo = rpdata[0].FirstName + " " +rpdata[0].LastName
```

You can debug the result to see what rpdata contains.